# Why receiving many Android In-app purchase orders with OLD ORDER ID in Feb 2014?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I've implemented Android In-app purchase using the Version 3 API and it working fines except I found some strange orders with `OLD ID FORMAT` returned by Google.

In order to counter check the IAP, I've stored all completed transaction returned by Google to our own server, but I discovered that there are many `orderId` with `OLD` format (no decimal).

Below are 2 extracts of the API return ("xxx" / "000" is a testing value):

**NEW ORDER ID:**

```
{
    "orderId": "12999763169054705000.1373263420600000",
    "packageName": "com.xxx.xxx",
    "productId": "com.xxx.xxx.af0",
    "purchaseTime": 1392983515012,
    "purchaseState": 0,
    "developerPayload": "xxx04392e9ca23874b14e8b31a37a05a",
    "purchaseToken": "xxxszpnnyymngwxhgjozzvdv.AO-J1Oy_bJ4gBTBBmtVF21Y9yPQvUOV-XEc2HZr11ci4ToxVrDXlMQ-YJDQswSV9si7M1sls9aM282AyWAUHzsd3xXtkQ7u3RjP1aaEnAL6E3Z0Stys3-uZFop_GYZZVkRUysGXDWfhV"
}
```

**OLD ORDER ID:**

```
{
    "orderId": "5485197040027619000",
    "packageName": "com.xxx.xxx",
    "productId": "com.xxx.xxx.af0",
    "purchaseTime": 1391011670305,
    "purchaseState": 0,
    "developerPayload": "xxx2ea5bf1a46f2636d96716cd38ca52",
    "purchaseToken": "xxxcoykgagbauiwzytybkdrt.hgZjTuN55caq1yQHfeZF3HHmtx3hUAJgMZk8CnpJsCdR2NfHgCMii3t_7MnZ5NHKW0-R4_9J3XD1qumJLhzfshYaoPLj-MAr5-Gacp9_nk1E1s-9x7wF70Y"
}
```

**My questions:**

1. I understand that the OLD format should be only used before 5 December 2012 (http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html), however, we just implemented the IAP recently (Feb 2014), how come we are still receiving many old order ids?
2. In my Google Wallet console, I only found the orders with NEW order id, and I don't know where can I check the orders with OLD ORDER ID in the console, I doubt if those transaction is valid.
3. For the OLD order ID, the `purchaseTime` always not correct, takes above as an example, we record the purchased time in our server as: **2014-02-23 06:13:07 GMT+8**, when we convert the "purchaseTime" (timestamp) to human readable date, it is: **Thu Jan 30 00:07:50 2014 GMT+8**, which is not possible as we didn't publish the IAP yet.

*Notes:*
In our record, there are 80% order with OLD ORDER IDs.

Comment: This means some people are either using old version of PlayStore or your app is getting hacked Using Freedom InApp cracker.