# App billing android orderId and currency format error

Tags: android, in-app-billing, currency

I'm using app billing v3 and Iabhelper interface, my implementation is ok (hope that) , but lately I'm getting this 2 problems with some registers:

1. Some orderId that I'm seding to my server are not in the normal format "orderId" : "GPA.1234-5678-9012-34567", I'm getting something like "556515565155651". Documentation say:

> "For transactions dated previous to 5 December 2012, you get "556515565155651".."

but this is a 2015 app, and this register is not showed in my google merchant account and finnancial reports.
My code is ..

```
    IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener= new          IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result,Purchase purchase)
    {
        if (result.isFailure()) {

             if (purchase!=null){
                 try {
                        String price =  Helper.getPriceSKU("mypackage", "mysku, "subs");
                        String currency = mHelper.getCurrencySKU("mypackage","mysku", "subs" );
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String orderId = purchase.getOrderId();
                    send_to_server(price, currency, orderId, "rejected");
             }
         } else {
                try {
                        String price =  Helper.getPriceSKU("mypackage", "mysku, "subs");
                        String currency = mHelper.getCurrencySKU("mypackage","mysku", "subs" );
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String orderId = purchase.getOrderId();
                    send_to_server(price, currency, orderId, "Aproved");

         }
    }
```

2. In some registers I'm getting the currency different. For example, my google account default has a PEN currency. One user is in Colombia and when I got his payment currency register it was PEN.. I know this is possible only if his google account and credit card is PEN, but strange thing is the prices is showed colombia local format... is possible a google error getting the currency? my code above.. thank you in advance!!

Comment: First question seems to be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21963426/why-receiving-many-android-in-app-purchase-orders-with-old-order-id-in-feb-2014?rq=1